# Uso de round() en T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

en un curso que estoy siguiendo de SQL server, he visto el uso de round() para comprobar los decimales de un campo en concreto; Este campo se llama haber, y lo usan de la siguiente manera `haber-round(haber,2)` En un principio, pese a no entender ese uso, he pensado que equivalía a `round(haber,2)` a secas, pero me retornas un número de registros diferentes.
He buscado información al respecto, pero nada.
¿ Podéis echarme un cable ? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El restar un valor del mismo valor pero redondeado, dará la diferencia que se generó al redondear. Eso puede ayudar para diversos cálculos o para verificar que los números no tuvieran decimales adicionales a los que deberían.

Lo más sencillo es mostrar un ejemplo con lo que pasa. Dejo el ejemplo con un valor que redondea hacia arriba, otro redondea hacia abajo y el último no necesita redondear.

```
SELECT haber,
       ROUND(haber, 2),
       haber - ROUND(haber, 2)
FROM (VALUES(35410.84313), (4134.4589), (546543.52))x(haber);
```